# select char from char array java lambda expression

Tags: java, c#, lambda

I'm looking for a solution to use lambda expression as it is used in this C# piece of code below. Is there a similar way in Java?

```
        string key = keyy;
        char[] tmpKey = keyy.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "").ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
        {
            char min = tmpKey.Where(o => o != ' ').FirstOrDefault();
            int index = tmpKey.Where(o => o == min).Select((o, ii) => ii).FirstOrDefault();
```

...

```
            tmpKey[index] = ' ';
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Not a Java expert & not sure these syntax will work, but in Java 8 you can use `stream` with filtering, e.g.: `char min = tmpKey.stream().filter((o) -> o.getKey() != '').findFirst().orElse(Character.DEFAULT);` and `int index = tmpKey.stream().filter((o) -> o.getKey() == min).map((o, ii) -> ii).findFirst().orElse(Integer.DEFAULT);`.